Interesting examples of lattice ordered abelian groups
Are there any interesting examples of lattice ordered abelian groups? Recall that a lattice ordered abelian group is an abelian group $G$ equipped with a lattice order $\leq$ such that for all $x,y,z \in G$, if $x \leq y$ then $z + x \leq z + y$.
Looking around online, I’ve been able to find very few examples of such groups. Most of the examples I have found follow one of the following structures:

totally ordered Abelian groups are lattice ordered abelian groups
if $G$ and $H$ are totally ordered Abelian groups, then their direct product $G \times H$ is a lattice ordered abelian group when equipped with the component-wise partial order, or the lexicographical total ordering
something on nLab about Bezout domains that I haven’t looked into closely.

Are there any other interesting examples? I’d love to see, for example, a lattice structure on $(\mathbb{R}^2, +)$ that isn’t a total order and isn’t the Pareto order. Does such a lattice structure exist?

Well, every vector lattice (= Riesz space) is a lattice ordered abelian group with respect to addition. In particular, a lot of function spaces are examples. But I'm under the impression that this is not really what you are looking for?

@JochenGlueck, I guess I’d like a lattice ordered group where I can both get my hands on it and do computations, but also have interesting behavior in the order. For example, the Pareto order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is certainly something I can understand, but the order structure is too simple. Same goes for anything totally ordered. I’m looking for a nice balance. Does that make sense?

I think the answer to your question, as it is stated, is yes, because as an abelian group $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, so any lattice order on that group will give you an order on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If, on the other hand, you want your abelian group to also have a real vector space structure compatible with the order (turning it into a so-called Riesz space), there is a structure theorem that sates that lexicographic and component-wise are essentially the only possible lattice orders.

This is less a direct answer than a hopefully-helpful comment, but: there is an analogue of Cayley's theorem for abelian $\mathscr{l}$-groups! Every abelian $\mathscr{l}$-group can be viewed as a group of real-valued functions on some partially ordered set. This is the Conrad-Harvey-Holland representation theorem; see Chapter 3 of Anderson/Feil's Lattice-ordered groups. At least to me, this helps explain the lack of "wild" examples of abelian $\mathscr{l}$-groups, although of course one's mileage may vary.
(It's also worth noting that there's a Cayley-type theorem for $\mathscr{l}$-groups in general: Holland proved in 1963 that every $\mathscr{l}$-group is (isomorphic to) a sub-$\mathscr{l}$-group of $\mathit{Aut}(L)$ for some linear order $L$, where $\mathit{Aut}(L)$ is construed as an $\mathscr{l}$-group via the ordering $f\le g\iff\forall x(f(x)\le_Lg(x))$. This is chapter 5 in Anderson/Feil.)
